# Creating chargingpoles after specific time

Tags: netlogo

I am wondering how to, after a number of ticks, create 10% more of the charging-poles and how to put that in code.

I now have

```
if ticks = (4032 + 4032) 
  [ask n-of (count aantal-laadpalen * 0.1) [create-laadpalen] ]
```

where `aantal-laadpalen` and `create-laadpalen` translated to English is the number-of-chargingpoles and create-chargingpoles.

This doesn't seem to work. Hope you can help me out!

Comment: Use `hatch` instead of `create`.  (Only the observer creates.)  Or you can ask patches to `sprout-laadpalen`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the whole `ask n-of` part with just:

```
create-laadpalen (count aantal-laadpalen * 0.1)
```

That's if you want the new agents to be created with default values. If you want the new agents to begin their lives as clones of their parents, then follow Alan's suggestion to use `hatch`:

```
ask n-of (count aantal-laadpalen * 0.1) laadpalen [ hatch 1 ]
```

Alan's suggestion to use `sprout` might also be appropriate if you want to place the new agents on random patch centers, instead of starting them at the center as `create-laadpalen` would do.